# CMake can't find Freetype

Tags: windows, cmake, freetype2

I'm trying to setup Freetype in my CMakeLists.txt file. (CMake 3.13)

```
cmake_policy(SET CMP0074 NEW)
find_package(Freetype REQUIRED)
```

But I got the error message:

```
[cmake] CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message): 
[cmake]   Could NOT find Freetype (missing: FREETYPE_LIBRARY) (found version "2.5.5") 
[cmake] Call Stack (most recent call first): 
[cmake]   C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE) 
[cmake]   C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindFreetype.cmake:156 (find_package_handle_standard_args) 
[cmake]   CMakeLists.txt:18 (find_package)
```

I opened the file of `FindFreetype.cmake`, it says:

> The user may set the environment variable `FREETYPE_DIR` to the root
>   directory of a Freetype installation.

so I did.My `FREETYPE_DIR` is set to `MY FOLDER OF\freetype\include`, the folder looks like this:

[freetype folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IkEV.png)

but I got the same error, no difference. (I have quit all cmd windows and my VSCode)

I also set the `FREETYPE_ROOT` to the same folder, just in case.

So which environment variable should I set?

Do I need to compile the Freetype project? (I only downloaded the source code but have not compiled)

Comment: `include` directory is almost **never** a root one. Try to use `MY FOLDER OF\freetype` as a hint. Note, that your root directory should contain `\\lib` subdirectory, which contains freetype library.